# Concluding about the relation of two monoids to a third a relation between the two monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Let $N, S, T$ be monoids and let $\varphi : N \to S$ and $\varphi' : N \to T$ be surjective homomorphisms such that for each $P \subseteq S$ there exists
some $Q \subseteq T$ such that
$$
 \varphi^{-1}(P) = \varphi'^{-1}(Q).
$$
Then there exists a surjective mapping from a submonoid of $T$ onto $S$.

Comment: I assume by S', you mean T?

Comment: yes! I corrected the notation.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this problem? I'm very happy to give more explanation if necessary. By the way, could you tell me where you came across it, as I'd be interested to find similar problems of this flavour.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer! I finally solved my problem, it arose as I tried to prove an assertion from the theory of formal language, if you are interested I can give you more information, but the other parts of the proof are not that similar, but one similar construction is the following (called *cover map*): Let $\varphi : T \to S$ be a surjective partial function, then if for each $s \in S$ there exists some $\hat{s} \in T$ such that for each $t \in T: \varphi(t\hat{s}) = \varphi(t) s$, then there exists a surjective morphism between $T$ and $S$.

Comment: You're very welcome. I wondered if the problem was an isolated exercise, or part of a bigger picture - but I only know a little bit of formal language theory. The definition you give of a covering map seems interesting, so I looked it up and found it discussed in _Algebraic Automata Theory_ by Holcombe. This reminded me that several years ago I came across a definition of 'covering' for (weighted) finite state automata, so now I am curious if there is a connection. Thanks a lot for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's temporarily forget about monoids and start with a claim that is purely about sets:

> **Claim 1** - Let $\varphi\colon N\to S$ and $\psi\colon N\to T$ be surjective functions such that for each $P\subseteq S$ there is some $Q\subseteq T$ satisfying $\varphi^{-1}(P)=\psi^{-1}(Q)$. Then there is a surjective function from $T$ to $S$.

To prove Claim 1 we need to come up with a function $T\to S$. So given $t\in T$, where shall we send it to in $S$? Since $\psi$ is surjective we know that $t=\psi(n)$ for some $n\in N$, so perhaps we could send $t$ to $\varphi(n)$.

However, we are only allowed to do this (i.e., this will only define a function $T\to S$) if $\varphi(n)$ does not depend on the choice of $n$. We therefore must check that if $t=\psi(m)$ for some $m\in N$ as well then actually $\varphi(m)=\varphi(n)$. *This is really the essence of the question, and I don't want to completely spoil it for you, so I won't give a proof of this bit yet.*

Now let's write $\chi\colon T\to S$ for the function we have just defined.
The key property to remember about $\chi$ is that $\chi\bigl(\psi(n)\bigr)=\varphi(n)$ for all $n\in N$.

To finish the proof of Claim 1 we need to check that $\chi$ is surjective. Since $\varphi$ is surjective, each $s\in S$ can be written as $s=\varphi(n)$ for some $n\in N$, and therefore $\chi$ sends $\psi(n)\in T$ to $s$. So yes, $\chi$ is surjective. Hence we have proved Claim 1. We can now deal with monoids:

> **Claim 2** - If $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are homomorphisms between monoids then $\chi$ is also a homomorphism.

This follows quickly from our definition of $\chi$. For example, to show that $\chi(1)=1$ we simply observe that we have $$\chi(1)=\chi\bigl(\psi(1)\bigr)=\varphi(1)=1,$$ because $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are homomorphisms. The other property of $\chi$ being a homomorphism - namely that $\chi(t_1t_2)=\chi(t_1)\chi(t_2)$ for all $t_1,t_2\in T$ - follows in a similar way.